# Subscript operator overloading to access a private array

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying to overload the `operator[]`, however, something funky is going on.

[To avoid long codes here, I put the code on GitHub (I'll keep the code as is there forever).](https://github.com/zafartahirov/GoodrichTamassiaCpp/blob/master/Issues/stackoverflow_operator%5B%5D.cpp)

The issue is that when I access the subscript, it doesn't return the `GameEntry` when accessing `s[0]`, but `Scores`. In addition to that the `<<` operator returns the whole array, while I was requesting only one of the entries.

Please, advise. Thanks

EDIT: The `operator[]` is declared on line 58.

Comment: You can link to a specific line by clicking on the line number to the left.

Comment: `GameEntry remove(int i) throw (IndexOutOfBounds);` Dynamic exception specifications are deprecated.

Comment: There are a bunch of other issues. I recommend putting your code on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) once it's working.

Comment: Thank you guys! All of these are actually helpful:

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60834/9357)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line declares *pointer* to `Scores`:

```
Scores *s = new Scores(5);
```

So instead of

```
cout << typeid(s[0]).name() << endl;
```

try

```
cout << typeid((*s)[0]).name() << endl;
```

Comment: That makes sense. What about the ```Scores::operator[]```? Isn't it supposed to return ```GameEntry```?

Comment: When you do `s[0]`, `Scores::operator[]` is not involved at all. We just access the first element from an array pointed by `s`. So `s[0]` is the same as `*s`.

Comment: Ah OK! Any suggestions how to modify the ```Scores::operator[]``` to make it access the entries?

Comment: Try `(*s)[0]`, `(*s)[1]` ... Or, maybe better, create `Scores` on the stack, without `new` operator.